# What are the minimum system requirements for analysing large datasets (30gb) in R?

Tags: r

I tried running Apriori algorithm on 30GB CSV file in which each row is a basket upto 34 items(columns) in it. So R studio died just after execution. I want to know what are the minimum system requirements like how much RAM and CPU config I need to run algorithms on large data sets?

Comment: R runs completely in-memory, so if you want to work with a 30GB data set then you would need at _least_ 30GB.  In practice, you would probably need _more_ than this, as the package you are using does math on this data.  Why do you need to work with such a large dataset?

Comment: Hi Tim, my current system config is 48gb and i7 processor still output of Apriori algorithm can not be obtained as it is giving low memory error. As I said, I need to do market basket analysis on a CSV file having transactional data.

Comment: @Praffulsingh Try which percentage of your data can be processed on  your current machine. Then limit the available memory to half, and try again. Then 1 quarter. These 3 measurement points should allow you to extrapolate roughly how much you need for the full data. (Perhaps supplemented with an extimate of Apriori's complexity given your input parameters)

Answer (score 0):

This question cannot be answered as such. It highly depends on what you want to do with the data.

## Example

1. If you are able to process all lines 1 by 1, you just need a tiny bit of ram (for example if you want to count them, I believe this also holds for the most trivial use of Apriori)
2. If you want to calculate the distance between all points efficiently, you will want a ton of ram, and another few GB to store the output (I believe this is even less intense than the most extreme use of Apriori).

## Conclusion

As such I would recommend:

Use whatever hardware you have to process a subset of the data. Check your memory and CPU usage, as you increase the data size (or other parameters) and extrapolate your results to see what you probably need.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Dennis. Does it has to do specifically with Apriori Algorithm or R studio will crash for other analysis also if we have large datasets ? Like if a function contains more loops( if - for etc.)  and we are passing large data sets through it, then there is a chance R studio might get crash.

Comment: @Praffulsingh In general, if you want to do analysis on a big dataset, you either need to find a way to do it piece by piece, or you need a big amount of RAM to prevent R from crashing. (How much is hard to say without tests).